# How to restrict public method access to superclass?

Tags: scala

In my Scala project, I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A {

  def methodA = ...
  ... other methods here ...
}

class B extends A {

  ... other methods here ...
}
```

In my class design, it makes perfect sense to make `B` a subclass of `A`. The only problem is that `methodA` is only applicable to class `A` but not to class `B`. Unfortunately, I cannot set `methodA` to private because it needs to be callable from any instance of class `A`.

Do I have to rethink my class design or is it possible to restrict the access to public method `methodA` to class `A`?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle By this, any instance of `A` should be replaceable by `B`, which is not the case if you have to restrict access to `methodA`, hence you should rethink your class design.

Comment: "The only problem is that methodA is only applicable to class A" - So why extend B to include this?

Comment: @brumScouse class `A` has some other methods that make sense for class `B` as well, except for this only one method `methodA`. That's why I extend class `B` with class `A`.

Comment: Why not extract used methods to another trait and extend it?

Answer (score 3):

> In my class design, it makes perfect sense to make B a subclass of A. The only problem is that methodA is only applicable to class A but not to class B.

These statements can't be true at the same time.

> Unfortunately, I cannot set methodA to private because it needs to be callable from any instance of class A.

Every instance of `B` is an instance of `A` (that's just what "subclass" means). So if the method isn't callable from an instance of `B`, it isn't "callable from any instance of class `A`".

Comment: I thought as much but I wasn't completely sure. Then I have to keep both classes separate and repeat the code for the common methods in both classes. I don't like it but apparently there's no other way.

Comment: @pemistahl You might want to have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem or consider moving shared code into a common trait.

Comment: @pemistahl No, you can have a superclass (or trait) which includes all actual common code. If you actually want `methodA` to exist in `B`, but not be public (because it's called in the implementation of other methods), it can be protected in the superclass and overridden to be public in `A`. Otherwise, just put it in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible way below:

```
class A protected() {
  //.... methods ....
}

trait AExt extends A {
  def foo(s : String) = println(s)
}

object A {
  def apply() : A with AExt = new A with AExt
}

class B extends A {
  //.... methods ....
} 

val a = A()
a.foo("hello")

val b = new B()
//  b.foo("hello") // no 'foo' method
```